# When to close a connection in PHP?

Tags: php, connection, pdo

Right now I open a connection (if one is not already opened) every time I think I will need one. The question is: when I do close it? At the end of each script that uses it? Is there a standard for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about PDO (your tag): Connections are automatically closed when your script terminates except you're using persistent connections.

It's not really necessary to close your database links yourself in normal web application unless you have long-running scripts (that don't require a continuous database connection).

Comment: Am I using persistent connections?

Comment: Depends on whether you have the `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` flag set or not. You can check the php documentation for further information: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

I've always closed them as soon as I was finished with them.  Why leave them open when you don't need them?